# How to float (left/right) 3 divs without space between them?

Tags: css

My navbar (940px for instance) contains 3 divs :

- One aligned left (automatic sizing) containing a menu
- One aligned right (defined size, 100px for instance) containing a logo
- One (automatic sizing) containing an input[type="text"] that should stick to left and right divs

Each div will have a different background/opacity, there must not have overlapping between them.

He is a drawing about what I need :

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|       MENU       |      INPUT TYPE TEXT (width: 100%)        |       LOGO      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Do you have an idea on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: make all of them to float left, put them in a container with whatever the total width required. Try this in http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link, we will get an idea and edit them as needed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vytM3/4/ check this fiddle. is this what you want?

Comment: Just to be certain, the parent container has a fixed width?

Comment: Hey guys, I just made a jsfiddle to explain my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/hBcsQ/ You'll see, I want my center div to stick to the right div too... Left and center divs should keep automatic sizing. Only right div has a specific size.

Comment: Give this a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/hBcsQ/1/

Comment: Well done ssorallen! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For some great reading on floats and column layouts, check out http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/ It was written in 2005, but floating hasn't changed since then.

Comment: doesn't overflow hidden just hide the fact its overlapping...

Comment: @Varubi What do you mean by "hide"? Without `overflow:hidden` on the center element, that center element will be the width of its container. Hiding overflow makes it the width of the space between the floating elements.

Comment: @ssorallen Nevermind, when I used chrome dev tools to inspect the center element it showed the element as being a lot larger than it really was. Basically making overflow work as a clipping mask, but when i set the input to 100% width it proved otherwise. That it indeed it was only taking the space it was provided and not just cropping stuff out of the view frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't float the center `<div>`. If you move it below the floating elements, it will sit between the floated elements. Adding `overflow: hidden` to the middle element prevents it from flowing beneath the floated elements.

HTML from your example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">menu1 menu2 menu3</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="center">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.left {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

.center {
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**check this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vytM3/4/) I made 3 div's and 1 container. hope it helps.

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.left
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

.center
{
    width: 68%;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    float: left;

}

.right
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. The OP didn't ask a 3-column layout. there are some conditions should be trigger.

Comment: Hashem sorry I don't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange your HTML so the elements are in this order:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">menu1 menu2 menu3</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="center">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;   
}
.left {
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
.center {
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hBcsQ/3/)**

Comment: Eerie! I came up with almost exactly the same code. I added `overflow::hidden` to the center element to make it only the width between the left/right floated elements, not the full width of their container.

Comment: @ssorallen - not sure that's needed,  but it depends on the OP's actual code. He seems to be specifying a height would could be adjusted as needed, and overflow:hidden may cutoff things that he may not want hidden.

Comment: @j08691 He asked for non-overlapping columns, *two* have dynamic `width` the *other one* has fixed.

Comment: Right floats should appear first in the HTML.

Comment: @j08691 Good point, although adding left/right padding on the center div would appear to not work properly because it would be the full width of its container. Making it the width that it appears to be seems like expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Move the item you want on the right to the first position in the HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="r">Logo</div>
  <div class="l">Menu</div>
  <div class="c">Center content</div>
</div>
```

Then it's simply CSS:

```
.wrap { background: #ddd; margin: 10px; }
.wrap > div { padding: 10px;}
.r { float: right; background: #aaa; width: 100px; }
.l { float: left; background: #eee; width: 100px; }
.c { text-align: center; }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/BqTdx/)